# calling template nonstatic method from partially specialized template method

Tags: c++

The following `method` call fails because it is declared as non-static function. I don't understand why.

```
struct Test
{
    template<typename T> method(){return T();}
    template<typename S> struct W;
    template<> struct W<int>
    {
        int meth()
        {
           return method<int>(); // method can't be called this way
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Post a [MCVE], with error.

Comment: What do you expect will happen here? You are aware the member function is non-static, so what's the `this` pointer for it? Where is the object?

Comment: `method` cannot be called this way. `struct W` is `Test`'s nested type, not a property of a particular object. You should either declare `method` static, so it can be called without a `Test` instance, or make the latter somehow known to `meth` (pass one as an argument, or whatever.)

Comment: @bipll - I believe you mistakenly typed your answer in a comment box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with templates, we can simplify the whole matter a little:

```
struct Outer
{
    void outerF() { }
    struct Inner
    {
        void innerF() { outerF(); }
    };
};
```

Although being defined inside another outer class, the inner one exists independently from the outer one. To be able to call the outer class' functions, you need an instance of the latter class, but there isn't any naturally (implicitly), so you need to provide one explicitly:

```
struct Outer
{
    void outerF() { }
    struct Inner
    {
        void innerF() { o.outerF(); }

    private:
        Outer o;
    };
};
```

Quite likely, you'd rather refer to the outer class in form of a reference or a pointer, being initialised in a constructor or (in case of pointer only) setter.